# jScrollPane bug? Page refresh breaks jScrollPane or something else is affecting it

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I notice the problem mostly with Firefox 3.6.6 on OS 10.5.8, and it happens occasionally with Safari (get your surprised face ready - IE actually works fine everytime - what?!).
My url is here:
http://culturewithinaculture.org/introduction.php
NOTE: It's password protected for now, as we haven't officially launched the site. 

**User**: cwac
**pass**: cwac2112

**Problem**: If you visit the link above it should load fine the first time.  Everything seems fine with the JS and CSS files.  HOWEVER, when you hit refresh it breaks.  Sometimes it takes 1 refresh, other times it takes 2 or 3.  The other odd thing is that if you wait 30 seconds or so and hit refresh it will be fine again.  Seems fairly random.  When I say it 'breaks' I mean it fails to apply the jScrollPane function to the DIV tags I have for the English and Japanese copy.

So I've tried loading the required JS files at different times with no luck yet.  For example tried loading the mousewheel.js file before and after the jScrollPane.js file.  I'm also using a link to the Google hosted version of Jquery, thinking that it could be requesting too much from our MediaTemple hosted account...perhaps a caching issue etc.  Here is the code I'm using to load all the necessary functions for the page (mainly using jScrollPane, and prettyPhoto for the video links):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// scrollpane code

    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();    

//Rollovers for navigation buttons

    $(".navBtn").hover(
        function(){
            this.src = this.src.replace("_org","_over");
        },
        function(){
            this.src = this.src.replace("_over","_org");
    });


//PrettyPhoto Function
$(function()
    {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
});
```

If you guys have any suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it.  I am definitely a newbie with jQuery, and this is my first site using only jQuery.  Anyone had this error with jScrollPane before?  Is there something funky about my CSS that is breaking this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but try loading your CSS files *before* your js files.

I seem to remember reading somewhere that your CSS should be defined before jQuery code. <s>I'm searching for that document. Will post it if I find it.</s>

**Update:**

It came from **Learning jQuery 1.3** by Jonathan Chaffer, Karl Swedberg

> To ensure that the page has also been styled before the JavaScript code executes, it is a good practice to place `<link rel="stylesheet">` tags prior to `<script>` tags within the document's `<head>` element.

Comment: +1 Yes, always load your CSS first. Great answer. Once you find that authoritative link that will be good to be able to reference.

Comment: @Doug - I was hoping it came from jQuery's docs, but turns out that it came from the part of **Learning jQuery** that I read. Still pretty authoritative as Swedberg is a jQuery team member http://jquery.org/team#karl-swedberg, and Resig wrote the forward.

Comment: You my man, are a LIFE SAVER.  I have NO idea why, but I thought it was not good to load the CSS before the java...that was the one thing I never tried.  Thanks so much.  Mystery solved.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with **patrick**, I have been testing your page for the past half an hour, yet no result. 
There should be some thing wrong  with CSS, I still don't understand How it worked fine for first time before reloading the page and crashing after reloading

Comment: Yeah it's all working now, thanks to Patrick's suggestion.  But yes it's weird that it was working the first time then randomly broke after you refreshed.  Strange.